# How to clear the cache of an application on IIS from another application?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, memorycache

I have an asp.net web api that holds objects using MemoryCache. The cache is for one week.

```
var cacheEntry = _cache.GetOrCreate(CacheKeys.Entry, entry =>
    {
        entry.SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(604800); //One full week
        return DateTime.Now;
    });
```

The purpose of this is to not hit the database on every call thus increasing performance of the application.

We want to be able to control the use of this cache through another GUI application.

Is it possible to clear the cache from another application that is also in ASP.Net?

Comment: use can use redis for this

Comment: unfortunately I can't use any 3rd party apps for this.

Comment: Design and expose an API to clear caches in the first Web API project, so that you can call in the second app. Otherwise, it is impossible to locate such caches from the outside.